# Why does my code try to allocate 140663756741808 bytes?

Tags: php, mysql, memory-management, laravel-5, dynamic-memory-allocation

Something is definitely wrong with my Laravel site. All of a sudden for the past few days - I've been getting error messages on a periodic basis in the logs of the following nature:

```
exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException'
   with message 'Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted     
    (tried to allocate 140663756741808 bytes)' in Unknown:0
```

There is no stack trace here and these messages seem to happen at two minute intervals sometimes three and sometimes every minute.

My error logs also log the page accessed when this error occurred and from what I've seen its almost every page. I haven't received any complaints yet from users as I'm assuming it takes place for a split second or so.

The error seems to indicate a demand for 140 terabytes which is ridiculously insane. And its pretty much almost always 140663756741808 bytes.

Has my code been hacked? Something deprecated overnight all of a sudden or is my server jinxed. There is no stack trace and I cannot follow to find where the problem may be - any ideas?

The site is built on Laravel 5.1, hosted on a Quad Core EC2 instance with an MySQL database on an RDS instance. Server is Apache.

Comment: Are they possibly on pages with a form? Are they on GET requests or on POST/PUT/DELETE requests? I would get some more logging in place to try to narrow down what the cause is.

Comment: did tried after restarting apache

Comment: Hmmm there are search forms on all the pages - its a standard search form. But aside that I'm not sure what else the issue might be...

Comment: Strange I did a server restart and the problem seems to have worked - thanks @RavishaHesh